# Exceeded maximum number of transactions per day Error in DragonMobile SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, speech-to-text

When i testing my app's Speech To Text function that used of Dragon Mobile SDK free trials, the following error was occurred.

```
Exceeded maximum number of transactions per day.
```

I want to know how many times can i use Speech To Text per day.

Is there anyways to solve that limitation without purchased their Gold Services?

Thanks for your times.

really sorry if i bother you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use up to 500 speech per a day.

Check [here](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=memberServicesSilver) for more detail for Silver Plan.